# ansible (2.5.0) search list of dictionaries (hashses) generator expression

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have a list of dictionaries, and I want one specific value.  The queue-port's node_port.

```
[
        {
            "name": "queue-port",
            "node_port": 32614,
            "port": 5672,
            "protocol": "TCP",
            "target_port": 5672
        },
        {
            "name": "cluster-port",
            "node_port": 31018,
            "port": 4369,
            "protocol": "TCP",
            "target_port": 4369
        },
        {
            "name": "dist-port",
            "node_port": 30732,
            "port": 25672,
            "protocol": "TCP",
            "target_port": 25672
        }
    ]
```

I know how to do this in python with lambda or a generator expression, I'm stuck when it comes to ansible accomplishing the same results.  It is an object generated from the openshift_raw module, so I might be just too noobish with python/ansible and making this more complicated then necessary.

```
register: opnshft_raw
```

`{{ opnshft_raw.results[0]['result']['spec']['ports'] }}` is the list I am trying to search through.

```
>>> (item for item in results if item["name"] == "queue-port").next()['node_port']
32614
```

Comment: Most voted answer in the dup-target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to parse the list variable in a loop with the set_fact module, and set a new variable to the value when the condition is met.

example:

```
  tasks:
  - name: parse and find value
    set_fact:
      my_variable: "{{ item.node_port }}"
    when: item.name == "queue-port"
    with_items: "{{ your_list_variable_name }}"

  - name: print results
    debug:
      var: my_variable
```